# APscheduler job with changing arguments and interval

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am using OpenCV to perform some calculations based on a screenshot I'm capturing in a while loop.

Inside this while loop, I have some actions that I want to be scheduled, so I tried to use APscheluder.

In order to simplify my question I wrote this example:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import random
import time

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

randomArea = 0
randomTime = 1
def calculate(randomArea, randomTime):
    print(randomArea)
    print(randomTime)

scheduler.add_job(calculate, 'interval', seconds = randomTime, args=[randomArea, randomTime])
scheduler.start()

while(True):

    time.sleep(1)
    randomArea = random.randint(-100,100)
    randomTime = random.randint(5,10)
```

In this case, my while loop will calculate `randomArea` and `randomTime` every second (because of the sleep(1)). My goal was that `job` will call `calculate` every `randomTime` seconds as they were calculated inside the while loop. In the current case, calculate job will be called every 1 second as it was initialized.

Is there any way I can tell the `job` to use the new calculated Area/Time and use them?

Basically, I want my next job to be scheduled based on a time calculated inside the while loop.

Thank you

Comment: is there an answer for this question?, I have similar case